# When it's necessary to have more than 1 instance of Blocker?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

In the documentation of [Blocker](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Blocker.html) there's the following paragraph:

> Instances of this class should *NOT* be passed implicitly because they hold state and in some cases, your application may need different instances of Blocker.

Why in some cases I would need more that one thread pool (and therefore more than 1 Blocker) for blocking operations?

Comment: Well, why not? You may want to have a fixed thread pool for reading and processing some CSV files and another unbounded thread pool for reading from a database, or any other combination. The point of the authors is that such decision can only be made by you as and user and they do not want to force us to only have one _(even if I have never had to use more than one)_.

Comment: Ok, right, the reason why I would want two blockers is to just break up different types of blocking operations to separate thread pools. I thought it might be another technical reason. Thanks!